# JFrame Image Icon

Tags: java, image, swing, icons, jframe

I'm only 13 and Java can be hard to understand. I need to change the icon in the top left hand corner on my screen but I can't figure it out. I have seen a lot of forum topics but don't understand it or where to put the method! Please Help!

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame 
{
      public Frame()
      {
          //options for the frame  
          setTitle("Builder");
             setSize(1000, 650);
             setVisible(true);
             setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
             setResizable(true);
      }
//shortcut setting
      public static void main(String[] args)
       {
             Frame f = new Frame();
       }
}
```

Comment: Pssss, that's great. I started at 15.

Comment: `i have seen allot of forum topics but don't understand it or where to put the method!` - Why do you think our suggestions will be any different? Post the code from the other forum topics that you have seen and tell us what you don't understand. We can't guess.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Show us the code; without it, we can't help.

Comment: I'm thirteen too, but I will close this. Sorry :)

Answer (score 7):

Familiarize yourself with the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html). Use `JFrame#setIconImage` where the frame gets initialized. You can use

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/icon.png"))
setIconImage(image);
```

Using [getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) removes the reliance on the local file system and also allows images to be loaded from JAR files.

Comment: +1 for Java Doc.  You could also use [`Window#setIconImages(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages%28java.util.List%29) and pass it a series of differently sized icons, allowing the system to choice the best icon for the OS - FYI

Comment: Also, shouldve mentioned `getResource` - its never too early to learn that one - will add :D

Comment: @MadProgrammer E.G. as seen in [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui) which has a 16x16 or 32x32 icon available as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
frame.setIconImage(myIcon);
```

Will do the job. myIcon is of type java.awt.Image